# ReactJS mobx-react TypeScript add types to injected props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx, react-typescript, mobx-react

How to add types to injected props from mobx-react inject?

I have few stores `{auth: authStore, ui: uiStore}`

I want to use it like this:

```
// give type authStore to prop called auth
inject('auth')(({auth}) => <div>comp</div>)   // now auth has type 'any'

// give type to extra props
inject('auth')(({auth, name}: {name: string}) => <div>comp {name}</div>)  // error given. 
// Property 'auth' does not exist on type '{name: string}'

// use generic types
inject('auth')(<Record extends {id: number, [key: string]: any}>
   ({auth, name, record}: {name: string, record: Record}) => <div>comp {name} {record.id}</div>)  // here same error
```

When I give type to injected props myself:

```
const FinalComponent = inject('auth')(({auth}: {auth: AuthStore}) => <div>comp</div>)
```

The FinalComponent receives a prop called auth as well. It should not receive that prop. Only the inner component should know about that prop.